# Combining rsync for data and Git for code

Tags: git, rsync

I have started using Git only recently and I am struggling with the following problem.

I run simulations on seven different machines and I am used to synchronise the content of the `~/Programs` folder so that all of them are up to date. I synchronise both data and the source codes using

```
rsync -naivuzh ~/Programs/ othermachine:Programs/
```

Recently, I have decided using git to try and better organize the different versions of my simulations that coexist (one code can be used for interacting or non-interacting systems, with different boundary conditions, etc.) and to be able to work on the codes in parallel to my students or collaborators. I, however, wanted only to save source codes through git and not the huge amount of data. I have thus created remote directories on github and added only the source codes and scripts to my git directories.

However, when I do the rsync, I have the impression that it messes up the Git directories: if I do a `git pull origin main` on a machine that *I think* should be up to date, there are often conflicts and problems. So here are my questions:

1. Is the general idea of what I am doing OK and should it be working smoothlessly? Or will the rsync mess up the `.git` repositories? (It could be that my problem is simply that I rsync changes which have not been committed yet...)
2. If this is bad practice, do you have a better idea?

Comment: What kind of conflicts are you getting? Are you talking about the generic use of the word, as in "problems", or do you mean "git merge conflicts"?

Comment: I have had both, hence the vague statement. I have had git merge conflicts, but also github issues: I was asked to provide again login & passwords even though my ssh key was recognised the day before without problems. My question is thus more general: is this the good way to proceed (and hence the only mistakes were human) or is there something fundamentally wrong with what I do.